# Change Color of Main Menu Custom Theme

Tags: shell, theme

I am trying to edit the text color for a selected application in the applications' menu. This "applications' menu" is opened upon pressing the Super Key. I am running pop os 22.04.
[image]

As you can see, the text is black and I'd like to make it white. I have a theme called "Material-DeepOcean-BL" and it is a bit confusing, since I have multiple folders in this theme's folder:

- gnome-shell
- gtk-2.0
- gtk-3.0
- gtk-4.0
  and others, but I do not think they are relevant.

I accessed the gtk-4.0 folder, but it also has two files, gtk.css and gtk-dark.css. I don't know which exactly I should be looking in, since in my Tweaks app I have only "Material-DeepOcean-BL" as a shell theme. I did not selected anything related to dark or white mode.

[image]

I have tried to change some colors in the above file ( which is gtk.css), but to no success. I am afraid to break something. They are too many colors to go by, such that I use the trial-and-error method.

My question is: **Can someone give me an idea of where I should look at? I bet these custom themes follow a pattern, so maybe you know better. I just want to change the text's color for the selected app in the menu that appears after the Super key.**

Thank you!